# amcharts chart does not show when div is initially closed by ng-show

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, amcharts

I have an amchart in a div whose show/hide is managed by angularjs. Sometimes it charts data that's already in memory. When that is the case, the div opens, chart is rendered and the SVG in there has a width of 10. As a result the chart does not appear on screen. Resize the window a mite and the chart appears because amcharts is listening to resize events I guess. This I think is a known issue - I have seen some SO posts on them and I hope one of them will work for me. My suspicion is that the angular machine does not get cycles to run open the div before amcharts gets to draw its magic (just a hunch no solid evidence.)

Next, I added an event watcher

```
piechart.write(divs.chart_div.attr('id'));
divs.chart_div.on('yes', 'snowy', function(){ // same with 'shown','resize'
    console.info('============= woah ========');
});
```

Now a strange thing happened. I see the following error stack in my console

```
Error: [jqLite:onargs] jqLite#on() does not support the `selector` or `eventData` parameters http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/jqLite/onargs
at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8762:12)
at jqLiteOn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11733:39)
at Object.JQLite.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11951:17)
at Object.makePieChart (http://localhost:8100/common/services/graphinghelperService.js:528:34)
at obj.controller.$scope.myExt.renderFunc (http://localhost:8100/directives/boxRenderers2.js:179:24)
at _render_it (http://localhost:8100/modules/dashboard/dashboard.js:246:30)
at $scope.showBox.deferred.promise.then.workarea.showChild (http://localhost:8100/modules/dashboard/dashboard.js:310:17)
at processQueue (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21888:27)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21904:27
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23100:28)
```

*And that funky behavior is gone* ! The chart appears if I click to redraw it out of cached data, hides when click again, and all good. No more bland background colored div to stare at!!.

However, if I change the watch to `divs.chart_div.on('shown', function(){` then the event handler is not called and the chart does not appear when rendered out of cached data.

I wonder what's going on.

Comment: A `watch` is angular's ability to respond to changing data by "watching" it. You're using events, not watches. Entirely different thing.

Comment: include jquery in your dependencies, the error clearly says why it is being thrown. angular internally uses jqLite, which doesn't supports selectors for **on** event.

Comment: amCharts does not rely on jQuery, so it can't be related to it being or not being loaded. Consider updating to the most recent version of amCharts library (3.14.2) it contains automatic watch for container size/visibility changes (as opposed to watching window size changes in earlier versions). If this fails, try tapping into Angular's events and call invalidateSize() on your chart object when the chart container is revealed.

Comment: Thanks. The upgrade modifies the behavior as suggested without having to tap into any events or invalidateSize()

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something (might be the armchart library?) is expecting jQuery to be available to bind to an event. Angular comes with jqLite, a stripped down version of jQuery so that's why you're getting that exception.

I'm guessing it's something here on this line.

```
at Object.makePieChart (http://localhost:8100/common/services/graphinghelperService.js:528:34)
```

Use the full version of jQuery instead to take care of that problem: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2752-using-jquery-instead-of-jqlite-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: You are right of course (and I don't want to use full jQuery), but what I am really curious about is why my chart suddenly began to appear...

Comment: My guess is that the dimensions of the html element can't be calculated at that point because they're not on-screen. I've encountered that problem with some other libraries. As an alternative to ngShow, one way to work around that is to create a CSS class that will position your chart off-screen somewhere. Use ngClass to apply the rule using the same condition as your ngShow used. HTML:`<div ng-class="{'hide-chart': !isChartVisible}">chart here!</div>` CSS:`.hide-chart { position:absolute; top:-9999px; left:-9999px; }`